# An unwanted object in the last cell of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code on a parsed XML array:

```
$(this).find("cp_group").each(function() {
    $("select#comp_1").append('<optgroup label="' + $(this).attr('label') + '"><option>' + $(this).find("cmp").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join("</option><option>") + $(this).append('</option></optgroup>'));
});​
```

And i get an unwanted [object Object] in the last option of each option group as following:

```
<select name="comp_1" id="comp_1">
<optgroup label="Combat">
<option>Arme</option>
<option>Arts martiaux</option>
<option>Esquive</option>
<option>Feinte</option>
<option>Parade</option>
<option>Lutte[object Object]</option>
```

I dont understand from where this [object Object] come from and I didn't achieve to not get it or to remove it.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's coming from the `+ $(this).append(...)`. You just want the `+'</option....'` part, without that jQuery wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood how jQuery, and in particular `append`, works. When you're manipulating things with jQuery, you're not dealing with **markup** (largely), you're dealing with **objects** (DOM elements).

This should fix it:

```
$(this).find("cp_group").each(function() {
    // Get this entry
    var $this = $(this);

    // Create the optgroup
    var optgroup = $('<optgroup label="' + $this.attr('label') + '">');

    // Fill it in
    $this.find("cmp").each(function() {
        $("<option>").text($(this).text()).appendTo(optgroup);
    });

    // Append it to the select
    $("select#comp_1").append(optgroup);
});​
```